# View resizing with images

Tags: ios, ipad

I got 10 views on main UIView with Buttons and Images on top of each single view, I managed to populate the ImageViews with remote Images, but I want to fit that Image on that entire screen, What I mean is fill the 10 variable views with Images. Any pointers please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set for every 10 buttons:

```
[yourbutton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill]
```

Comment: make button custom with your images in uiview.

Comment: Thank you Bro, got it, you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036936/button-on-top-of-other-button-but-the-one-on-top-should-be-transparent-since-t